# Jsoup doesn't take the full html source code from the URL, Why ?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape video links from an official facebook page using Jsoup. When i connect with Jsoup and try to display the content of the document that it contain the HTML codes after connection, it display a portion of HTML codes not the full one. I even used a user agent but i still receive a portion of code source code source.
Why when i right click normally from the browser to display the code source it appears the full one with the div, comments etc. but using Jsoup it's not ? Help please

```js
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

  public class xxxx {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        print("running...");
        Document d2;
 
   
   
   
   try {   d2=Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/pg/EttounsiyaTV/videos/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167")
   .maxBodySize(0)
   .timeout(600000)
   .get();

 System.out.println(d2);
 
  } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        print("done");
    }

    public static void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fb page needs logged user? How you are logging with jsoup?

Comment: You might need selenium webdriver for this

Answer (score 1):

**NO** you cannot fetch the dynamic content using JSOUP. But for explanation i am giving you below details.

Here is what you want to get using JSOUP.

```html
<video muted="1" height="462" width="820" preload="auto" style="" class="_ox1 _21y0" data-video-width="820" data-video-height="462" data-original-aspect-ratio="1.7777777777778" id="u_0_r" src="blob:https://www.facebook.com/b7dc6f31-ec0a-4df3-aac5-feb341dc8a29"></video>
```

[image]
**The problem**

[image]
but if you search the page source , you are not able see what you are trying to get using JSOUP it means you cannot fetch the things which are not rendered on the page source using JSOUP those are dynamic contents rendered using javascript or any other source. For that you have to use SELENIUM or any other tool which imitates the browser activity programmatically.

Comment: Thank you so much, i appreciate your help